# Remove nth bit from buffer, and shift the rest

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Giving a `uint8_t` buffer of `x` length, I am trying to come up with a function or a macro that can remove nth bit (or n to n+i), then left-shift the remaining bits.

example #1:

for input `0b76543210 0b76543210 ...` then output should be `0b76543217 0b654321 ...`

example #2: if the input is:

```
uint8_t input[8] = {
    0b00110011,
    0b00110011,
    ...
};
```

the output without the first bit, should be

```
uint8_t output[8] = {
    0b00110010,
    0b01100100,
    ...
};
```

I have tried the following to remove the first bit, but it did not work for the second group of bits.

```
/* A macro to extract (a-b) range of bits without shifting */
#define BIT_RANGE(N,x,y) ((N) & ((0xff >> (7 - (y) + (x))) << ((x))))
void removeBit0(uint8_t *n) {
    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
        n[i] = (BIT_RANGE(n[i], i + 1, 7)) << (i + 1) |
               (BIT_RANGE(n[i + 1], 1, i + 1)) << (7 - i); /* This does not extract the next element bits */
    }
    n[7] = 0;
}
```

[image: bits]
**Update #1**
In my case, the input will be uint64_t number, then I will use `memmov` to shift it one place to the left.

**Update #2**
The solution can be in C/C++, assembly(x86-64) or inline assembly.

Comment: On x86, there's an instruction for that (wait, what?): `pdep/pext`, added by the `BMI2` instruction-set extension.

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting, I am giving it a try.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the question. The diagram suggests you do not just want to remove one bit, but actually want to remove bits *s* + 8 * *i* from a stream of bits represented by an array of *x* octets, where *s* in [0,7], i.e. this is a particular form of bit stream compaction. A naive way would be to simply loop over the input bits, keeping separate running tallies of the number of bits for source and destination that indicate when to suppress the bit copy and when to retrieve/deposit the next octet. Would that be too slow for your purposes?

Comment: @njuffa Ideally the method should be cross-platform, fast and works with other data types beside uint8_t, but for now I just want it to work, I am trying looping over elements approach, but could not get it work.

Comment: What are typical values of *x*, i.e. what is the anticipated length of the bit stream? I am thinking of fast unrolled variants based on the fact that the extraction pattern repeats after 8 input / 7 output octets (so partial unroll by a factor of 8 leads to efficient 64-bit processing plus handling of possible end cases).

Comment: @MohamedEl-Sayed - You need to pick up two bytes at a time into a short or int, shift the bits as wanted, then store a single byte. Advance the pointer or index by one byte, and repeat the process. At some point you'll be skipping 8 bits, in which case the source pointer or index will be 1 or more greater than the destination pointer or index.

Comment: If this is supposed to be "cross-platform", why have you used the "assembly" and "inline-assembly" tags? Also you haven't answered njuffa question about how your diagram contradicts your question.

Comment: Pick a language please.

Comment: @rcgldr I think your approach should work, but I stuck in the actual low-level coding.

Comment: @RossRidge The reason I have added assembly it that once I get the general idea, I can replicate it for other platforms(mainly x64 and mips) and post it here.  I am sorry, I do not see the contradiction between the question and the diagram, but in case it was not clear, each block represents a single byte.

Comment: The first line of your question says you want to remove one bit (or a range of consecutive bits) from a buffer. The diagram shows multiple non-consecutive bits being removed.  You have to decide on whether your question is asking for a cross-platform solution or a platform specific solution. In the former case it would be inappropriate for you to post a platform specific answer, and in the later case you need to name the platform.

Comment: @RossRidge I apologize for the confusion, but I was looking for a generic approach to the problem, I have updated the question and added x86-64 as a preferable ISA, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really 2 subproblems: remove bits from each byte and pack the results. This is the flow of the code below. I wouldn't use a macro for this. Too much going on. Just inline the function if you're worried about performance at that level.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Remove bits n to n+k-1 from x.
unsigned scrunch_1(unsigned x, int n, int k) {
  unsigned hi_bits = ~0u << n;
  return (x & ~hi_bits) | ((x >> k) & hi_bits);
}

// Remove bits n to n+k-1 from each byte in the buffer,
// then pack left. Return number of packed bytes.
size_t scrunch(uint8_t *buf, size_t size, int n, int k) {
  size_t i_src = 0, i_dst = 0;
  unsigned src_bits = 0; // Scrunched source bit buffer.
  int n_src_bits = 0;    // Initially it's empty.
  for (;;) {
    // Get scrunched bits until the buffer has at least 8.
    while (n_src_bits < 8) {
      if (i_src >= size) { // Done when source bytes exhausted.
        // If there are left-over bits, add one more byte to output.
        if (n_src_bits > 0) buf[i_dst++] = src_bits << (8 - n_src_bits);
        return i_dst;
      }
      // Pack 'em in.
      src_bits = (src_bits << (8 - k)) | scrunch_1(buf[i_src++], n, k);
      n_src_bits += 8 - k;
    }
    // Write the highest 8 bits of the buffer to the destination byte.
    n_src_bits -= 8;
    buf[i_dst++] = src_bits >> n_src_bits;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  uint8_t x[] = { 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa };
  size_t n = scrunch(x, 4, 2, 3);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%x ", x[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This writes `b5 ad 60`, which by my reckoning is correct. A few other test cases work as well.

**Oops** I coded it the first time shifting the wrong way, but include that here in case it's useful to someone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Remove bits n to n+k-1 from x.
unsigned scrunch_1(unsigned x, int n, int k) {
  unsigned hi_bits = 0xffu << n;
  return (x & ~hi_bits) | ((x >> k) & hi_bits);
}

// Remove bits n to n+k-1 from each byte in the buffer,
// then pack right. Return number of packed bytes.
size_t scrunch(uint8_t *buf, size_t size, int n, int k) {
  size_t i_src = 0, i_dst = 0;
  unsigned src_bits = 0; // Scrunched source bit buffer.
  int n_src_bits = 0;    // Initially it's empty.
  for (;;) {
    // Get scrunched bits until the buffer has at least 8.
    while (n_src_bits < 8) {
      if (i_src >= size) { // Done when source bytes exhausted.
        // If there are left-over bits, add one more byte to output.
        if (n_src_bits > 0) buf[i_dst++] = src_bits;
        return i_dst;
      }
      // Pack 'em in.
      src_bits |= scrunch_1(buf[i_src++], n, k) << n_src_bits;
      n_src_bits += 8 - k;
    }
    // Write the lower 8 bits of the buffer to the destination byte.
    buf[i_dst++] = src_bits;
    src_bits >>= 8;
    n_src_bits -= 8;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  uint8_t x[] = { 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa };
  size_t n = scrunch(x, 4, 2, 3);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%x ", x[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This writes `d6 5a b`. A few other test cases work as well.

Comment: Thank you, this actually works, I was going to point out the endian issue, but you have already mentioned that, so, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to this should work:

```
template<typename S> void removeBit(S* buffer, size_t length, size_t index)
{
  const size_t BITS_PER_UNIT = sizeof(S)*8;

  // first we find which data unit contains the desired bit
  const size_t unit = index / BITS_PER_UNIT;
  // and which index has the bit inside the specified unit, starting counting from most significant bit
  const size_t relativeIndex = (BITS_PER_UNIT - 1) - index % BITS_PER_UNIT;

  // then we unset that bit
  buffer[unit] &= ~(1 << relativeIndex);

  // now we have to shift what's on the right by 1 position
  // we create a mask such that if 0b00100000 is the bit removed we use 0b00011111 as mask to shift the rest
  const S partialShiftMask = (1 << relativeIndex) - 1;

  // now we keep all bits left to the removed one and we shift left all the others
  buffer[unit] = (buffer[unit] & ~partialShiftMask) | ((buffer[unit] & partialShiftMask) << 1);

  for (int i = unit+1; i < length; ++i)
  {
    //we set rightmost bit of previous unit according to last bit of current unit
    buffer[i-1] |= buffer[i] >> (BITS_PER_UNIT-1);
    // then we shift current unit by one
    buffer[i] <<= 1;
  }
}
```

I just tested it on some basic cases so maybe something is not exactly correct but this should move you onto the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much, I like how you took the time and provided a template function but unfortunately this does not produced the desired output, I am trying to modify the code a little bit to get to work with a uint8_t buffer.